# Is it possible to insert a value into the last index of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, methods, insert

So i've noticed recently that it isn't possible to insert a value into the last index of a list using the "Insert" method and was wondering if there was some extra step i need to take in order to do so or if it's simply not possible. If using "Insert" is not possible i'd appreciate it if any one knows a method of going about it. I know how accomplish it without the "Insert" method but if there's a better way i'd prefer that. I am aware that you can simply get the length of the list and the use it as the index.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the append method. Like this

```
a.append(x)
```

This inserts x to the last index of the list `a` i.e. to the end of list `a`.
For example:

```
a = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges"]
a.append("lemons")
print (a)
```

This would print:

```
["apples", "bananas", "oranges", "lemons"]
```

You can also use insert to do it like this:

```
a.insert(len(a), x)
```

But the `insert` method used above is very inefficient and not very readable either. So I suggest you use the `append` method.

For more info, visit https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use something like this?

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l.insert(len(l),5)

print l

[1,2,3,4,5]
```